# MS access: Merging 02 tables into 01

Tags: ms-access, merge, vba

I am using Microsoft Access database (Please don’t suggest me to use some other database since I donot have that choice in this particular situation).
I have 02 tables as below.

Table 1: Purchase Order

```
    PO_No, Item_No, Order_Qty  
    01       a         10  
    01       b          5  
    02       a          8  
    02       b          2
```

Table 2: Stock

```
   Item_No, Batch_No, Qty  
      a       0001     5  
      a       0002    50  
      b       0003    10
```

=> I would like to create something like this:

```
   Item_No, Batch_No, Ship_Qty, PO_No  
      a       0001       5        01  
      a       0002       5        01  
      a       0002       8        02  
      b       0003       5        01  
      b       0003       2        02
```

Please help!

Comment: do you know how to make a query?

Comment: if you know how to use both those tables in a query, then its only one more step to combine them into a query.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some code.

Comment: Sorry, I have just edit the tables again. Please help!

Comment: Again, what you need is a simple query.

Comment: @John - you should have left the tables how I edited them for you, in the `code blocks`.  Also, you need to answer the questions you are being asked.

Comment: @Andre: It seem that impossible for a simple query to deduct quantity

Comment: @ashleedawg: Ofcouse I know to make some types of query. I tried to use union query but the result was wrong. I edited the tables in the code blocks. Please help!

Comment: No, not a union query..  Start with a regular `Select` query with a regular join between the two tables. Do you know how to do that?  ...because once you get that, one more step will have the results output to a new table. If you don't know how to do that then there is no point in me explaining.

Comment: @ashleedawg: I think simple query make wrong result. I tried this but incorrect:

SELECT Stock.Item_No, Stock.Batch_No, [Purchase Order]![Order_Qty]-[Stock]![Qty] AS Ship_Qty, [Purchase Order].PO_No
FROM [Purchase Order] INNER JOIN Stock ON [Purchase Order].Item_No = Stock.Item_No;

Comment: Then you don't know how to make a Select query with 2 tables.  (One of the simplest types of queries.)  I'm afraid this site is not the right place for beginner's lessons but I will write an Answer with resources for you now.  You should also see the [tour] and then read over [help/on-topic] as well as [ask].

Comment: @ashleedawg: Thank you for your help!. I will read carefully the help center again.

Comment: You're welcome.  Read all of the links, both above, and below ([in the answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052176/8112776))

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:  *Make-Table Example*

You still need to read through at least some of the links that I posted earlier but I don't think you we getting what I meant so here's an animation to show you the steps.

1. Create Select Query from the 2 tables
2. Test Select Query to make sure output is what you want in new table
3. Convert Select Query to Make Table Query
4. Execute Make Table Query

[image: animated example]

This is a very short process, just a few minutes.

Good Luck.

---

### STEP 1:

First you need to create a Select Query using both of your tables, joined together, similar to this:   (See the tutorials at the bottom of this answer.)

[image: query]

---

### STEP 2:

Once the Select Query is producing the data how you want it organized, you can convert it to a Make Table query:

[image: maketable]

---

## Tutorials:

1. **[Skillshare : Intro to Access - Microsoft Access Basics for Beginners](https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Intro-to-Access-Microsoft-Access-Basics-for-Beginners/1032598850)**
2. Microsoft.com : **[Introduction to Queries: Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-queries-d85e4893-0ed7-4118-8297-785a01357516#__toc264892221)**
3. YouTube : **[Acccess 2016: Multi-table queries](https://youtu.be/pcjXQqKWWNw)**
4. Office.com : **[Join tables and queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6)**
5. Microsoft.com : **[Create a make-table query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b)**

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway! Actually, I knew how to make "make-table query" but the result here is not simple like this. I will try to make code then ask for help later.

Comment: No code!  Just a query!  Don't worry about the make table query until Step 1 is done.

Comment: Great effort! @ashleedawg

Answer (score 0):

Well kudos to ashleedawg for that effort.

In the end - your very first step must be to make a select query that will result in the records/fields correctly of what will be the new table.

The second step is then to make a Make Table Query.  But that can wait for now.

In glancing at your 2 source tables, and the resulting 3rd table you seek - - I did not see any join logic that would create that result.  If you can explain what is the logic  - - then help with that select query can be provided.